# Поможет ли обновление BIOS запустить linux

Tags: linux

[image: Разметка]Извините если вопрос слишком глупый. Я установил на жёсткий диск Pop os (рядом с windows 7) и на пк система запускаеться и работает идеально но когда я подключаю диск к ноутбуку он почему-то говорит что дисков нету (диск GPT загрузчик UEFI) Установочную флешку UEFI он прекрасно видит и запускает а диск не хочет. На форумах говорят о EF02 но я ещё слишком мало понимаю для этого + новая разметка не подходит так как мне нужно что бы данные windows остались нетронутыми

Answer (score 1):

EF02 - bios boot нужен для того чтоб установить legacy загрузчик на gpt разметку. Он не нужен если ноут настроен не на легаси.

EF00 - раздел куда устанавливается загрузчик EFI.

EF02 нужен размером до 2х мегабайт. Можно снести раздел EFI, откусить там немного для биос бут и пересоздать efi.

Comment: Извините но я только начинаю осваивать линукс и поэтому не совсем понимаю что именно должен сейчас делать. Я прикрепил фото со своей разметкой (Знаю что выглядит скорее всего ужастно просто я уже два дня пытаюсь это решить и перепробовал много вариантов)

Comment: EF02 у тебя есть. что за ошибка в квадратике?

Comment: sda5(Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sda5 is missing)

Comment: sda1( Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for fat32 file system support:  dosfstools, mtools.)

Comment: sda5 Я намерено создал без файловой системы исходя из того что нашел в интернете

Comment: Также по поводу sda1, dosfstools установлена с коробки а вот mtools я доустановил после этого gparted перестал ругаться (установил и на саму систему и на загрузочный диск)